# How to create a string using concat to assign to a variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-send-dbmail

I'm using the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure, and I'm trying to include the result from a query in the body string. I can't seem to get this to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
use msdb
go

exec sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'WarehouseEmailer',
    @recipients = 'someone@example.com',
    @subject = 'Database Mail Test 1',
    @Body = 'This is a test email from SQL Server. <br> This should be line 2. <br> The 
    subject\'s first name is: '+ (select top(1) FirstName from Warehouse.dbo.Subject),
    @body_format = 'HTML'
```

Obviously this example just a simple test, but it is exactly the type of data I'd like to pass to the stored procedure to include in the email body. I look forward to your responses and many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL, or concatenated strings, cannot be passed into the procedures parameters like that.

Try this:

```
use msdb
go
declare @msgbody nvarchar(1000)
set @msgbody = 'This is a test email from SQL Server.' + char(10) + 'This should be line 2. <br> The 
    subject''s first name is: '+ (select top(1) FirstName from Warehouse.dbo.Subject)

exec sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'WarehouseEmailer',
    @recipients = 'someone@example.com',
    @subject = 'Database Mail Test 1',
    @Body = @msgbody,
    @body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and concise answer Jiggs! I assume then that I can wrap the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure in another stored procedure (declaring additional variables for other non-static variables like recipients)?